# How can I "split" the virtual keyboard when typing on a large display in landscape mode?

Tags: keyboard, tablet

I have a large Android tablet and would like to "split" the virtual keyboard when it's in landscape mode. [Something similar like the iPad feature.](http://www.itechblogger.com/index.php/2012/ipads-split-keyboard-ios-5/)

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Thumb Keyboard** allows for this, as well as many other handy features which make it well worth the money

[Paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beansoft.keyboardplus) Version

[7 Day Trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beansoft.thumbkb_demo) Version

Answer (score 6):

Swiftkey's tablet version supports this ([paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.tablet.full), [free trial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.tablet.trial)). It has the letters split to each side and the numeric keys in the middle:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There also is [FloatNSplit Tablet Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android.tablet) (for the tablet rather [AI FloatNSplit Tablet Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aitype.android.tablet.p)) which offers this feature:

[image: Float'n'Split] [image: Float'n'Split]

In addition to being able to split the keyboard, this one can also float with some transparency:

[image: Float'n'Split transparent]