# How to read 2 or more documents side-by-side in Android?

Tags: pdf, multi-window

When I do my math exercises, I need to view the book and the exercises at the same time. Sometime I need to open a third PDF, but it's more optional. How can I do so with Android? On iPad I use the application [Side by Side](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/side-by-side-dropbox-support/id386528623?mt=8), which allows to read up to 4 different PDFs side by side.

I use Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: In order to help you, we need some more information, like: What brand and model of device do you have? What version of Android does it have? Add any other additional info you guess it can be of use to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try using floating apps. Multi window feature is only available on a few android devices like samsung Note, etc.

Floating apps will provide similar functionality. Try this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lwi.android.flappsfull

Answer (score 3):

You may also look here: [How do I run two programs at once in split-screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40638/how-do-i-run-two-programs-at-once-in-split-screen)

Tested on a Samsung Note 10.1 (SM-P605) with Android 4.3 i found some apps which are supporting multi window, e.g:

- My Files (*)
- stock Video Player
- MX Player
- stock email app
- Gmail
- stock Webbrowser (*)
- Chrome
- Gallery
- Contacts
- Phone
- Google maps
- Polaris Office 5
- WhatsApp
- Facebook
- Watch now
- Chat on (*)
- Google Play Store

But there are really very few apps capable to run with multiple instances (from the above list only those which are marked with (*)).
So, you can for example open `My Files` twice (left & right of upper & lower half screen):

[image: Screenshot My Files side by side]

Unfortunally, `Polaris Office 5` (pdf viewer) isn't capable to run twice. So if you want to view 2 pdf docs side by side, it seems that you have to install a 2nd pdf viewer app and e.g. open `Polaris Office 5` on the left and the other pdf viewer on the right side of the screen. A short look to Google Play Store for pdf viewers that support multi window:

- [PDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pdf.reader) from Ivan Ivanenko (free)
- [Ebooka PDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebooka.pdf) from Ivan Ivanenko (free)
- [RepliGo PDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app) (paid, 2,26€)

At the following screenshot I had opened Ivan Ivanenko's PDF Reader & Ebooka PDF Viewer side by side:

[image: Screenshot 2 pdf side by side]